# How can I reference a dynamically created ID in HTA (vbscript)?

Tags: vbscript, hta

See slimmed down code. I'm essentially creating a list of items (printers) along with a dynamically created unique radio button ID, and then I'd like to be able reference said Radio ID in order to toggle the Checked between True/False in Sub SetDefaultPrinter. Why? Because using Add Devices / Search is too hard for some of our users, hence, a cute little GUI. Why dynamic? Because I have multiple separate networks and I'd prefer the script to adjust itself as needed.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My HTML application</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
APPLICATIONNAME="My HTML application"
ID="MyHTMLapplication"
VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

Public jj, strPrinters, strModels, strLocations

Sub Window_OnLoad
strPrinters = Array("Printer1", "Printer2")
strModels = Array("HP Color LaserJet 4525", "HP Color LaserJet 4525")
strLocations = Array("Room 1", "Room 2")

jj = UBound(strPrinters)

Call OnClickGo()
End Sub

Sub OnClickGo()
DataArea1.InnerHTML = ""
For i = 0 To jj
        DataArea1.InnerHTML = DataArea1.InnerHTML & "<BR><font style=color:green;font-weight=bold;>" &_
          "<input type=""" & "radio""" & " name=""" &_
          strPrinters(i) & "Radio""" & " id=""" & "Radio" & i & """" &_
          " title=""" & "Clicking here will set " & strPrinters(i) & " as default printer.""" &_
          " onclick=""" & "SetDefaultPrinter(" & i & ")""" & " onmouseover=""" & "Pointer""" &_
          " onmouseout=""" & "DefaultCursor""" & "></input>" &_
          "<span id=""" & strPrinters(i) & "Span""" &_
          " title=""" & "Click here delete printer mapping for " & strPrinters(i) & """" &_
          " onmouseover=""" & "Pointer""" & " onmouseout=""" & "DefaultCursor""" &_
          " onclick=""" & "OnClickDelete(" & i & ")""" &_
          ">" & strPrinters(i) & ", " & strModels(i) & ", Location: " & strLocations(i) & "</span></font>"
Next
End Sub

'========================================
'= Set Default Printer ==================
'========================================
Sub SetDefaultPrinter(ii)
DataArea2.InnerHTML = strPrinters(ii) & " would have been set as default if this was fully functional."
'
' Radio0 and Radio1 are dynamically created IDs, *really* want to somehow
' dynamically reference the dynamically created IDs.
' i.e. something like
'     If ii <> 0 Then (Radio & ii).checked = False
'
If ii <> 0 Then Radio0.checked = False
If ii <> 1 Then Radio1.checked = False
End Sub

'========================================
'= Delete Printer Mapping ===============
'========================================
Sub OnClickDelete(ii)
DataArea2.InnerHTML = strPrinters(ii) & " would have been deleted if this was fully functional."
'Set wshnetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
'wshnetwork.RemovePrinterConnection "\\SERVER\" & strPrinters(PrinterToDelete)
End Sub

'========================================
'= MOUSE Pointers =======================
'========================================
Sub Pointer
document.body.style.cursor = "hand"
End Sub

Sub DefaultCursor
document.body.style.cursor = "default"
End Sub
</script>
<body bgcolor="white">
<span id="DataArea1"></span>
<BR><BR><BR>
<span id="DataArea2"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

user2345916, I have modified your code where the variables pass like you wanted.  I left your comments intact, so you can pick up where you left off.  Hope this helps!

Basically, the answer to your problem lies within the button's "ID", "VALUE" and "ONCLICK" values.

- The ONCLICK='SetDefaultPrinter(" & i & ")' will pass the looped number to the SubRoutine.
- The SetDefaultPrinter(Radioii) sets a variable from the "ONCLICK" field of the button that sends you to that SubRoutine (In this case, it's a 0 or 1).
- The "FileName = document.getElementById("Radio" & Radioii).value" gets the "VALUE" field of the button that matches the "ID" field that is set between the "()", which in your case is also the variable that was pulled from the ONCLICK.
- From here, you can use (FileName) variable to do whatever you want (Match IF/THEN, etc)

  ```
  <script language=vbscript>
  Sub Window_OnLoad
  window.resizeTo 500,300
  strPrinters = Array("Printer 1", "Printer 2")
  strModels = Array("HP Color LaserJet 4525", "HP Color LaserJet 4525")
  strLocations = Array("Room 1", "Room 2")

  jj = UBound(strPrinters)
  For i = 0 To jj
  strHTML1 = "<span id='Delete" & i & "' value='" & strPrinters(i) & "'title='Click here delete printer mapping for " & strPrinters(i) & "' onmouseover='Pointer' onmouseout='DefaultCursor' onclick='OnClickDelete(" & i & ")'> " & strPrinters(i) & " - " & strModels(i) & ", Location: " & strLocations(i) & "</span>"
  strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<input type='radio' name='radio' value='" & strPrinters(i) & "' id='Radio" & i & "' title='Clicking here will set " & strPrinters(i) & " as default printer.' onclick='SetDefaultPrinter(" & i & ")' onmouseover='Pointer' onmouseout='DefaultCursor'>" &_
  "" & strHTML1 & "</input><br>"

  DataArea1.InnerHTML = strHTML2
  Next
  End Sub

  '========================================
  '= Set Default Printer ==================
  '========================================
  Sub SetDefaultPrinter(Radioii)
  FileName = document.getElementById("Radio" & Radioii).value
  DataArea3.InnerHTML = Filename & " would have been set as default if this was fully functional."
  '
  ' Radio0 and Radio1 are dynamically created IDs, *really* want to somehow
  ' dynamically reference the dynamically created IDs.
  ' i.e. something like
  '     If ii <> 0 Then (Radio & ii).checked = False
  '
  If Radioii = 0 Then Radio0 = False
  If Radioii = 1 Then Radio1 = False
  End Sub

  '========================================
  '= Delete Printer Mapping ===============
  '========================================
  Sub OnClickDelete(Deleteii)
  RemoveName = document.getElementById("Delete" & Deleteii).value
  DataArea3.InnerHTML = RemoveName & " would have been deleted if this was fully functional."
  'Set wshnetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
  'wshnetwork.RemovePrinterConnection "\\SERVER\" & strPrinters(PrinterToDelete)
  End Sub

  '========================================
  '= MOUSE Pointers =======================
  '========================================
  Sub Pointer
  document.body.style.cursor = "hand"
  End Sub

  Sub DefaultCursor
  document.body.style.cursor = "default"
  End Sub
  </script>
  ```